# Argument of type 'ConnectionBackend' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConnectionBackend'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question trying to figuring out what the issue here. I have created a custom Http class, ExtendHttp, which extends the Angular2 Http class and packaged it as a npm module. It compiles and test cases run within the project, but when I import it into other project using the npm module, it will give an error saying:

> severity: 'Error' message: 'Argument of type 'ConnectionBackend' is
>   not assignable to parameter of type 'ConnectionBackend'.   Types of
>   property 'createConnection' are incompatible.
>       Type '(request: any) => Connection' is not assignable to type '(request: any) => Connection'. Two different types with this name
>   exist, but they are unrelated.
>         Type 'Connection' is not assignable to type 'Connection'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
>           Types of property 'request' are incompatible.
>             Type 'Request' is not assignable to type 'Request'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
>               Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
>                 Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'Headers'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
>                   Types have separate declarations of a private property 'mayBeSetNormalizedName'.' at: '35,42' source: 'ts'

This is my custom Http Class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ExtendedHttp extends Http {
    private logger: Logger;
    constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
                private config: ApplicationConfiguration,
                private evtsrv: EventService) {
        super(_backend, _defaultOptions);
        this.logger = new Logger(config.getLoggerConfig());
    }
...
}
```

This is how I use it in my other project:

```
@NgModule()
export class CoreModule {
    static forRoot(authzrule: AuthzRule[]): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: CoreModule,
        providers: [
        { provide: UserSessionStorageService, useClass: UserSessionStorageService },
        {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: (xhrBackend: ConnectionBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions,
            config: ApplicationConfiguration, evtservice: EventService) =>
            new ExtendedHttp(xhrBackend, requestOptions, config, evtservice),
        deps: [ConnectionBackend, RequestOptions, ApplicationConfiguration, EventService]
},
```

Comment: Please post the code of the custom Http class.

Comment: Please add also the relevant parts of `AppModule` and the imports you're using

Comment: So where do you import `HttpModule`? Please add your TypeScript imports as well.

Answer (score 0):

After realizing writing the CoreModule on the project where I import the npm module is a bad idea, hence moving the writing of CoreModule back to originate project and package it together with the npm module to resolve the issue.

Thanks  Günter Zöchbauer for time & effort, you make realize where I have gone wrong.