# Typescript duplicated type declarations

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm

I'm experiencing issues with duplicated Typescript type declarations in the following case:

I've got the following dependency tree for my application A:

```
A->@angular/http:2.3.1
A->B->@angular/http:2.3.1
```

Both A and B are managed by npm. After running

```
npm install
```

the filesystem looks like this:

```
A/node_modules/
  @angular/http
  ...
  B/node_modules
     @angular/http
```

The problem seems to be that now there are two type declarations of @angular/http types like *Response*, or *Headers*. And somehow the Typescript transpiler seems unable to handle that - resulting in the following error message:

> TS2453:The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred
>   from the usage. Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
>   Type argument candidate 'Response' is not a valid type argument
>   because it is not a supertype of candidate 'Response'. Types of
>   property 'headers' are incompatible. Type 'Headers' is not assignable
>   to type 'Headers'. Types have separate declarations of a private
>   property 'mayBeSetNormalizedName'.

Reading the message, I guess this is a hickup of Typescript not being able to match the duplicated type declarations.

Anybody experienced the same issue? How to handle that problem? How to handle such name collisions?

Comment: I know there is this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412938/argument-of-type-connectionbackend-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-con. The answer's not really satisfactory, because in my case I cannot (do not want to) simply move the sources from B into A. There must be another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile I found out that you can fix this error by explicitly importing the according types inside the using class of A. In my case (cp. error message above), I needed to:

```
import {Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. There are basically two ways to solve this.

1. Make a UMD module of project B. This might take a lot of time
2. use `as any as TheRequiredObject` see below.

Let assume you got this class in project b:

```
export class B{
    getSome(): Observable {
        return this.http.get('some_url');
    }
}
```

and this is what you want in project a:

```
export class A{
    getSomeFromB: Observable{
        return B.getSome() as any as Observable;
    }
}
```